Ubuntu 24.04 new install terminal will not accept password from keyboard
Just had to do a complete re install of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS after I was unable to clear a fault with a software update package. Using a new Logitek MK 345 keyboard / mouse combo but unable to enter password after first line of text in the terminal. BUT, freecad and other applications accept keyboard number inputs no problem. Have tried to install specific keyboard driver for keyboard, all to no avail. Any ideas please on how to rectify this problem.

To be clear the issue is only with numbers? Are you referring to the number pad?

In Ubuntu it is a normal behavior that the system takes the password but does not show any characters for extra security. Is that not what you see?

David, Thanks 4 yr reply. Using number line on top of keyboard as Ubuntu wants (or needs) pw with letters and numbers. When typing in PW, cursor does not move. Its just useless. Seriously considering reverting back to Win 10. I have had computers since Apple 2E. Cheers Graham B

Archismann, Thanks 4 yr reply. Cursor dos not move when PW typed in, press RTN and next line asks for PW again, so I suspect that its a settings or system problem. Regret ever considering using this manky operating system Seriously considering going back to Win 10. Cheers Graham B

Here are some suggestions to solve this problem:
Test password entry in other applications such as a text editor to confirm that the problem is specific to the terminal.
Possible solutions
Run a complete system update to ensure all drivers are up to date:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

Resetting terminal settings
Close all open terminal windows.
Delete the terminal configuration file:
rm ~/.config/gnome-terminal

Restart the terminal and test again.
Temporarily change the terminal input mode:
Open a terminal using the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T :)
Type stty -a to display current settings.
Disable password echo:
stty -echo

Test password entry.
To re-enable echo:
stty echo

It's also possible that a security setting is interfering with password entry. Check the following configuration files:

/etc/login.defs
/etc/pam.d/common-password
Look for unusual lines related to password entry.
Try using an alternative terminal like xterm to see if the problem persists:

sudo apt install xterm
xterm

If the problem doesn't occur in xterm, this could indicate a problem specific to gnome-terminal.
Otherwise
Create a new user account and test if the problem persists.
Reinstall the gnome-terminal package:
sudo apt remove --purge gnome-terminal
sudo apt install gnome-terminal


Lotti - thanks for your reply. Problem still exists in that I am unable to even get beyond the first entry in command line because it asks on the next line for your password - and this will not accept any input from the keyboard. Hence its b...y useless, wish I had never installed this Store High In Transport operating system and considering going back to Windows 10. Utter waste of time and effort. Cheers Graham B

I did find a youtube video in Hindi which gave instructions on how to fix the problem. I took a screen shot but was unnable to copy and paste the text. Well done ubuntu text editor!!! Rapidly tiring of ubuntu C  R  A  P making return to W10 more likely. Cheers.
